# Programming audio to a voice ROM

Tags: audio, eeprom

I own an arcade crane machine that stores its music on a API840N sound chip and i'd like to change the music that the machine plays, I've taken a look at the data sheet but it doesn't go into detail on how audio is programmed onto it's internal EEPROM.

Could someone explain to me the easiest way I can go about reprogramming this sound chip?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://pdffile.icmartonline.com/pdf_file_A/20200531/pdf_pdf/pdf1/APLUS/API840_datasheet_128180/209379/API840_datasheet.pdf) is a datasheet.

You cannot re-program this device- it is one-time programmable only. This was a magnificent improvement from the mask-programmed parts we had to source prior to OTP EPROM availability, at least for prototypes and small quantities. The mask-programmed parts had a large minimum order quantity, significant lead time, and mask charges, and if you got it wrong there was no recourse other than discarding the parts and starting over.

You could buy another chip and program it, but you would probably have to source the programmer that the manufacturer sold for it (and being 22 years old, they're likely a bit hard to source). I doubt they made the programming information public.

I see some NOS chips identical to yours (note: it is **not** a sure thing that they are not already programmed with something and thus useless to you) and some used programmers available from China for about $100, but they're for a slightly newer version of the chips and not listed as compatible. They would also probably require XP or some earlier O/S such as Windows 98.

The manufacturer APLUS (a fabless Taiwan company) still exists. [Here](http://www.aplusinc.com.tw/exec/msg.php?mid=6&cid=4&pid=6&lg=E) is their website.

Comment: If you could reverse-engineer how the audio is stored, it may also be possible to use a more modern chip in place of the old one, possibly with some kind of translation layer if it's a nonstandard pinout.

Comment: @Hearth I think I would go more for a functional replacement though some of the chips I linked may be compatible. I used similar parts in that era in a project from a US company, and AFAIR they output a block of sound when appropriate inputs are triggered. Editing the sound was just a matter of putting it in the required sound format (.wav maybe) and then the programmer software converted it into some compressed PCM format at the desired bit rate. Fidelity was pretty miserable but the latency to get the sound started was very short. I'm not sure the modern MP3 modules would be suitable.

Comment: I think I used Cool Edit Pro. The company was bought by Adobe and it eventually became Adobe Audition.